# How to remove repeating headings

Tags: php, search, pagination

spent hours unsuccessfully trying to figure this out, just not a good coder.  I have 2 headings called title and date and I'm trying to stop them from repeating before every row. I just want the heading once at the top.  What do I have to change to accomplish this.  Thanks!!!!     Use bitcoin to search.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
          <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Title</th>
          <th class='table-header' width='5%'>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>



<?php
define("ROW_PER_PAGE",15);
require_once('db.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{width:615px;font-family:arial;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:20px;}
.tbl-qa{width: 100%;font-size:0.9em;background-color: #f5f5f5;}
.tbl-qa th.table-header {padding: 5px;text-align: left;padding:10px;}
.tbl-qa .table-row td {padding:10px;background-color: #FDFDFD;vertical-align:top;}
.button_link {color:#FFF;text-decoration:none; background-color:#428a8e;padding:10px;}
#keyword{border: #CCC 1px solid; border-radius: 4px; padding: 7px;background:url("demo-search-icon.png") no-repeat center right 7px;}
.btn-page{margin-right:10px;padding:5px 10px; border: #CCC 1px solid; background:#FFF; border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer;}
.btn-page:hover{background:#F0F0F0;}
.btn-page.current{background:#F0F0F0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
    $search_keyword = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :keyword OR description LIKE :keyword OR post_at LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id DESC ';

    /* Pagination Code starts */
    $per_page_html = '';
    $page = 1;
    $start=0;
    if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
        $page = $_POST["page"];
        $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
    }
    $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
    $pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
    $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pagination_statement->execute();

    $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
    if(!empty($row_count)){
        $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
        $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
        if($page_count>1) {
            for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                if($i==$page){
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
                } else {
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
                }
            }
        }
        $per_page_html .= "</div>";
    }


    $query = $sql.$limit;
    $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
}
?>
<form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
<div style='text-align:right;margin:20px 0px;'><input type='text' name='search[keyword]' value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword' maxlength='25'></div>

    <?php
    if(!empty($result)) { 
        foreach($result as $row) {
    ?>
<table class='tbl-qa'>


<thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Title</th>
      <th class='table-header' width='5%'>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody id='table-body'>
      <tr class='table-row'>
      <td><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['post_at']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?php echo $per_page_html; ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're recreating the table in your foreach loop (<table ...> ... <tbody>), it should only include the html for your row (the <tr>...</tr> part)

Comment: table needs to be outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

This way it will works:

Array to test (use your $result in your case)

```
$result=array(
array('post_title'=>'title 1','post_at'=>'at 1'),
array('post_title'=>'title 2','post_at'=>'at 2'),
array('post_title'=>'title 3','post_at'=>'at 3'),
)
```

Html:

```
<table class='tbl-qa'>
<tr>
    <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Title</th>
    <th class='table-header' width='5%'>Date</th>
</tr>
<?php
    if(!empty($result)) { 
        foreach($result as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr class='table-row'>
            <td><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['post_at']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

As you can see, the header if written just once because it is out of the loop whilst the row inside the loop will be repeated.
Finally close the table out of the loop.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/a8814009/public_html/index.php on line 107

Comment: I don't know which is you line 107. 
My code just has 28 lines and it is working correctly. I also added an array so you can test it.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo  Having 1 more problem.  The Title and the Data headings are showing up before I do the search.  See what I mean at http://vince.netau.net    If trying search use the term bitcoin

Comment: You are welcome Vinman64. About your second issues, please try to be more specific. 
Post the  code you are testing, what it is expected to do and what it is really doing. This way is easier to everybody to help. 
As it is a new problem, open a new question and accept the answer for this one.